# Convert colorspace of image in PHP (RGB to CMYK) without php-extensions like Imagick

Tags: php, jpeg, rgb, cmyk, color-space

Can i convert colorspace of jpg image, without using third-party libraries like Imagick.
WIth using native php functions only.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of color extraction and management functions exposed by **GD** extension which is bundled with PHP.
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

**Note that CMYK support was added in 2.0.22 of The GD extension.**